# avoiding error with empty variable in prepared statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
        var publicFunctions = new PublicFunctionsController();

        if (!publicFunctions.CheckSession(Session["id"])) { RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); };

        

        var src = DateTime.Now;
        var date = new DateTime(src.Year, src.Month, src.Day, src.Hour, src.Minute, 00);

        var arrow = OverUnder == "Over" ? $"EndTime >= {date}" : OverUnder == "Under" ? $"EndTime <= {date}" : "";
        var userCategories = Categoriesb == "" ? "" : $"Categories IN ({Categoriesb})";
        var lastId = $"Id > {Id}";
        var firstAnd = arrow == "" ? "" : "AND";
        var secondAnd = userCategories == "" ? "" : "AND";
        var sortByViews = ifViews == 1 ? "ORDER BY Views DESC" : "";

        //var strin = $"SELECT TOP 5 StatementTitle, Statement, ArgumentTitle, Argument, Explanation, Categories, EndTime, SessionId, Id FROM Statements WHERE {arrow} {firstAnd} {userCategories} {secondAnd} {lastId} ORDER BY Id DESC {sortByViews}";
        //the above works when used as query but below does not

        var queryString = "SELECT TOP 5 StatementTitle, Statement, ArgumentTitle, Argument, Explanation, Categories, EndTime, SessionId, Id FROM Statements WHERE @arrow @firstAnd @userCategories @secondAnd @lastId ORDER BY Id DESC @sortByViews";

        List<SingleStatementBlog> data = new List<SingleStatementBlog>();

        var con = publicFunctions.Connection();

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con); //figure out or for like clause
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrow", arrow);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstAnd", firstAnd);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userCategories", userCategories);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondAnd", secondAnd);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastId", lastId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sortByViews", sortByViews);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //error at first and
```

When I run the query with parameters I get an error saying "error at firstAnd" but when i run the query without parameters it works(as seen in the comments). I am wondering if an empty string "" is the reason why this is failing...

Comment: You can not pass statements as parameters, only actual values can be passed as Sql parameter

Comment: I wouldn't need a prepared statement if i am checking the values before hand right?

Comment: yeah i don't need one i dont think considering they are all new values i created.

Comment: Note the answer correctly dispose SqlConnection and Command with `using` blocks. Note also [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not pass** statements as parameters to the query, instead pass actual values.

You can use `StringBuilder` to build sql query with parameters based on conditions.

```
    var src = DateTime.Now;
    var date = new DateTime(src.Year, src.Month, src.Day, src.Hour, src.Minute, 00);

    var query = new StringBuilder();
    query.AppendLine(@"
      SELECT TOP 5 StatementTitle, Statement, ArgumentTitle, Argument
          , Explanation, Categories, EndTime, SessionId, Id 
      FROM Statements 
      WHERE 1 = 1");
    
    if (OverUnder == "Over")        
    {
        query.AppendLine("AND EndTime >= @date");
    }
    if (OverUnder == "Under")        
    {
        query.AppendLine("AND EndTime <= @date");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Categoriesdb) == false)
    {
        query.AppendLine($"AND Categories IN ({Categoriesb})");
    }

    if (ifViews == 1)
    {
        query.AppendLine("ORDER BY Views DESC")
    }
    else
    {
        query.AppendLine("ORDER BY Id DESC")
    }

    using (var connection = createMyConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), connection))
    {
        var param = new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime) {Value = date};
        command.Parameters.Add(parameters);

        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Read the data
        }
    }
```

It is important to create SqlParameter with correct database types, this will improve performance of the query and reduce possible type errors.

Notice that when you passing Categoriesb, you are still passing "raw" data to the query.
Consider to use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the one = one trick... can't believe i did not think of this at first!